# Simulating a 2D rope from a top down perspective

Tags: software-engineering, graphics-programming, procedural-generation

I was wondering if anyone could point me to any resources and/or explain how to properly simulate a 2D rope from a top down perspective?

I found a game that has the exact mechanic I'm looking for...

http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/300760

Play at least one level to get an idea of what I mean.

Comment: That is not a mechanic I'd like to see in any game I play. It was quite frustrating.

Comment: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=40

Comment: @wangburger The mechanic in itself isn't frustrating, just the game/level design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of that "shoe string" is achieved by using splines. You will find a lot of resources by just googling that keyword.